# Calling C++ DLL by pushing a button in C# GUI

Tags: c#, c++, button, dll, dllimport

I have a DLL with the following C++ exported function:

```
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void*OPS_FDD(const char* char_Address,const int int_NumChann,const int int_SamplingFreq){
    FDD* FDD_Ptr_Object=NULL;
    if(FDD_Ptr_Object==NULL){// if condition to avoid memory leak
        FDD_Ptr_Object=new FDD(char_Address,int_NumChann,int_SamplingFreq);
    }
    if(FDD_Ptr_Object==NULL){
        //throw "allocate memory to FDD object pointer: could not be done";// can not throw inside __declspec(dllexport) functions marked extern "C"
        std::cout<<"Error: allocate memory to FDD object pointer: could not be done"<<'\n';
        system("pause");
    }
    delete FDD_Ptr_Object;// de-allocate the pointer to avoid memory leak
    FDD_Ptr_Object=NULL;// set the pointer to NULL
    return NULL;
}
```

Now I want to call this DLL by pushing a button in my C# GUI. What lines of code should I write in the following space available for adding code to the button. By the way, the name of my DLL is "FDD_DLL"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace callDLL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // what lines of code should be here to call my C++ DLL
            // by pushing this C# GUI button ???
            // by the way, the name of my DLL is FDD_DLL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read the page you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use P/Invoke, something like this:

```
 [DllImport( "FDD.DLL" )]
 private static extern IntPtr OPS_FDD( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] string char_Address, int int_NumChann, int int_SamplingFreq );
```

Which you can then more or less call like any other method. The thing now is that how you declare the extern all depends on what the different arguments mean. For example, in this case, `char_Address` can be passed to the C++ dll in several ways - several different ways of representing strings, if it even is mean to be a string, that is. The `MarshalAs` attribute is used to specify what you want. Without more information this is my best guess.

More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx).